# Railsでリストから複数の行を削除する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Railsで管理画面を作っています。
リストページで全ての行の前にCheckBoxを置いて、Checkされた行を全部削除したいんです。

下記は自分のコードです。

```
table.table.table-bordered.table-striped
  thead
    tr
      th
      th #
      th 会社コード
  tbody
    - @companies.each do |company|
      tr
        td.text-right = company.Id
        td = company.CompanyCode
        td.text-center = link_to '詳細', company, class: 'badge bg-green'
        td.text-center = link_to '修正', edit_company_path(company), class: 'badge bg-light-blue'
        td.text-center = link_to '削除', company, data: {:confirm => '本当に削除してもよろしいでしょうか？'}, :method => :delete, class: 'badge bg-red'
```

controller

```
before_action :set_company, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /company
def index
  @companies = Company.all
end

# GET /company/1
def show
end

# GET /company/new
def new
  @company = Company.new
end

# GET /company/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /companies
def create
  @company = Company.new(company_params)

  if @company.save
    redirect_to @company, notice: 'company was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /companies/1
def update
  if @coupon2_type.update(coupon2_type_params)
    redirect_to @coupon2_type, notice: 'Coupon2 type was successfully updated.'
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

# DELETE /companies/1
def destroy
  @company.destroy
  redirect_to companies_url, notice: 'Company was successfully destroyed.'
end

private

# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_company
  @company = Company.find(params[:id])
end

# Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
def company_params
  params.require(:company).permit(:CompanyCode)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`check_box_tag`の中に配列を置き、それを用いてコントローラ側で削除すればうまくいくと思います。
`<%= check_box_tag "words_info[]",word.id %>`
こんな感じです。